# Doing spreadsheet style operations using awk

Tags: awk

I have a data file:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Now I want to add the first and second number, second and third numbers and so on and receive the data file:

```
1 
2 3
3 5
4 7
```

And then remove the first row to get:

```
2 3
3 5
4 7
```

I could have used spreadsheet but I need to use gnuplot for plotting. So I really want to use awk for this task.

Comment: OK, so what is it you are having trouble with? This is a very simple, straightforward thing to do in awk. Which part of it is confusing you? What do you have so far?

Comment: I have no experience using awk. That is the trouble.

Comment: Now could be a good time to gain that experience. If you get stuck we're here to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really trivial in `awk`. By default, `awk` will read its input file and apply whatever script you tell it on each line. It will split the line on whitespace (by default, you can choose another delimiter using `-F`), and the first field will be `$1`, the second `$2` and so on.

With this in mind, what you need is a simple script that i) saves the value of the previous line in a variable and ii) if we have a previous value (so, if this isn't the first line), prints the current first field plus the sum of the last line and the current first field. in other words, this:

```
$ awk '{if(last){print $1, $1+last;} last=$1}' file 
2 3
3 5
4 7
```

Or, equivalently

```
awk 'last != "" { print $1, $1 + last } { last = $1 }' file
```

or,

```
awk 'NR > 1 { print $1, $1 + last } { last = $1 }' file
```